# save new data to user table using asp identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity

I am trying to add a piece of data to the Asp identity table which stores user details (`AspNetUsers`). I have code to create a new user but not how to add or change things in a table. Could someone link me a resource or show me an example of how to do this?

For example if I created users where age was null and had a form that asked a user to input an age and wanted to add that to the users information without having to create a new user.

I have all the code to collect the variable.

I have added migrations for the new columns and created the columns in the table, I just need to add the data for the user that is currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
user.Age = 25;
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

Comment: i get: the await operator can only be used within an async method.

Comment: if you are not using async in your method you can use this code `var user = UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
user.Age = 25;
var result = UserManager.Update(user);`

Comment: now i have Using the generic type 'UserManager<TUser, TKey>' requires 2 type arguments

Comment: I think you are doing it the wrong way can you share your code