# Implement asp identity to save data to user table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin, identity

I am trying to save a piece of data to the same file that I use to hold my user information with asp.identity `AspNetUsers` and I have created new columns through migration etc..

I don't know how to use the actual code in order to implement this

I currently have but I know it's wrong and cant seem to find out why:

```
if (score != 0);
{
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    user.COLUMN_IN_TABLE = score;
    manager.Update(user);    
}
```

where `COLUMN_IN_TABLE` is the column that I am trying to use.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, if only you had an answer, 12 hours of nothing

Comment: Based on this and the last 2 questions from you, you have every intention of using the identity database for more than user authentication and authorization data. Why don't you create a database of your own to store all this data, and link the data using the user id from the identity data? What you are attempting is not something you should move forward with.

Comment: yeah, after hours of trying i decided that this was the better idea, i didn't think that it would be possible to connect to more than 1 server in order to save data and assumed that i would need to re-code my entire solution to save user data to a different database. i appreciate the responce

Comment: This is the [duclicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307810/save-new-data-to-user-table-using-asp-identity) question